# Upload photo from Windows 8 to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, windows-8

The Azure SDK don't working on Windows 8 APP.

How I can upload photo to Azure Blob Storage from Windows 8 App?

I need working code sample.

Comment: Assume you are using the Windows 8 Azure SDK? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/05/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-windows-runtime.aspx

Comment: I got error when trying add using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Windows Azure SDK to upload photos from Windows 8 applications to Blob Storage. The HttpClient will also work fine:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     CameraCaptureUI cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureUI();
     StorageFile media = await cameraCapture.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.PhotoOrVideo);
     using (var fileStream = await media.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
     {
          var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
          content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", media.ContentType);
          content.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");

          var uploadResponse = await client.PutAsync(
                                        new Uri(blobUriWithSAS), image);
     }
}
```

The only thing you'll need to do is get the url to the blob together with the Signed Access Signature. [Nick Harris explains](http://www.nickharris.net/2012/09/windows-8-how-to-upload-an-image-using-a-blob-storage-sas-generated-by-windows-azure-mobile-services/) how you can do this using mobile services.

Comment: Thanks but what url shoult I put in new URI()?

Comment: I got error: Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid